# Not able to click the radio button using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a problem clicking the Radio button for the Registered Projects [on this site](https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/searchlist/search). It is not clicking with my code in selenium webdriver.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
link =driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search Project Details")
link.click()
driver.find_element_by_id("Promoter").click()
```

Comment: Can you post your output error?

Comment: I didn't get the error, just the website get open but it is not clicking the Registered projects radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and java Scripts Executor to click on the `Registered Project` radio button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search-pro-details']//a[contains(.,'Search Project Details')]"))).click()
Registered_Project_radio= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Promoter")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Registered_Project_radio)
```

### Browser snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
driver.get('https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in')
link =driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search Project Details")
link.click()
time.sleep(2)
radio_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("Promoter")
radio_btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Above code not working. I'm getting the error 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="Promoter" name="Type" onchange="Checkboxck('Promoter')" type="radio" value="Promoter"> is not clickable at point (298, 190). Other element would receive the click: <div id="dvProgress" class="loader" style="opacity: 0.529567;"></div>

Comment: I have added a wait(time.sleep(2)) try this.
maybe that was due to page loading

Answer (score 0):

[WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) - An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,\
                "search-pro-details")))

#Click on Search Project Details link
links.find_element_by_link_text("Search Project Details").click()

promoter_radio_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,\
                "Promoter")))

#select radio button
promoter_radio_button.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```